# Windows Service with .NET 6 not running with WebApplication builder

Tags: c#, windows-services, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I am having the following error when trying to create a windows service:

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.NotSupportedException: The content root changed from "C:\WINDOWS\system32" to "C:\foo\foo\publish". Changing the host configuration using WebApplicationBuilder.Host is not supported. Use WebApplication.CreateBuilder(WebApplicationOptions) instead.

My builder:

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services...

    builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

    builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.File(_logDir)
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));

    WebApplication app = builder.Build();
    app.Run();
```

It works with `IHostBuilder`:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateServiceHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        ..
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you need to set your `ContentRootPath` with `WebApplicationOptions`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    ContentRootPath = @"C:\foo\foo\publish",
    Args = args
});
```